# JSoup parsing a text file containing a html table with Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am really unsure how I can get the information I need to place into a database, the code below just prints the whole file.

```
File input = new File("shipMove.txt");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, null);    
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

My HTML is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10480432) from line 61 and I am needing to get the items under the column headings but also grab the MMSI number which is not under a column heading but in the href tag.  I haven't used JSoup other than to get the HTML from the web page.  I can only really see tutorials to use php and I'd rather not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those information, the best way is to use **Jsoup's selector API**. Using selectors, your code will look something like this (pseudeocode!):

```
File input = new File("shipMove.txt");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, null);


Elements matches = doc.select("<your selector here>");

for( Element element : matches )
{
    // do something with found elements
}
```

There's a good documentation available here: [Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). If you get stuck nevertheless, please describe your problem.

Here are some *hints* for that selector, you *can* use:

```
// Select the table with class 'shipinfo'
Elements tables = doc.select("table.shipinfo");

// Iterate over all tables found (since it's only one, you can use first() instead
for( Element element : tables )
{
    // Select all 'td' tags of that table
    Elements tdTags = element.select("td"); 

    // Iterate over all 'td' tags found
    for( Element td : tdTags )
    {
        // Print it's text if not empty
        final String text = td.text();

        if( text.isEmpty() == false )
        {
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this has definitely pushed me in the right direction.